# Trying to return a promise for React-Select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a type here:

```
type Person = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
};
```

And I have a block of code as promise here which gets the data from the API - then it transforms it to the correct type of array for the react component and then I hope to return it using the return command in a promise - like so:

```
const fetchDropDown = async () : Promise<Array<Person> | string>  => {
  try {
  const stuff = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]);
  const records = stuff.value;
  const options = records?.map(d => ({
    "value": d.name,
    "label": d.name
  }));
    console.log(options)
    return options
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

But it is giving me all sorts of errors on the return options line:

> Type '{ value: any; label: any; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to
> type 'string | Person[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'string | Person[]'

I think it is because it is an array that I am passing back and the Person type is not an array, but I don't know much about TypeScript.

Also on the React component itself it is error where I am putting the load options:

```
  <div>
       <AsyncSelect
          cacheOptions
          defaultOptions
          loadOptions={fetchDropDown}
        />
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const fetchDropDown = async () : Promise<Array<Person> | undefined >  => {
  try {
  const stuff = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]);
  const records = stuff.value;
  const options = records?.map(d => ({
    "value": d.name,
    "label": d.name
  } as Person));
    console.log(options)
    return options
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't like where the <Person> type is on the map. This is killing me!!! lol

Comment: I have done it with map<Person>(d  => ({ and now I am getting lots of horrendous errors on the react component : () => Promise<Person[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: OptionsOrGroups<Person, GroupBase<Person>>) => void) => void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Person, GroupBase<...>>>'.
  Type 'Promise<Person[] | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<Person, GroupBase<Person>>>'.

Comment: I am so nearly there - can you please just give me a final push please.

Comment: Any ideas anyone ???

Comment: Sorry, forget this is a TSX file, please use as Person to convert type.

Comment: Thanks for that Peter can you just give me an example on how to do this please ?? Then I’ll answer your question correct please

Comment: I have done this : return options as Person and I am getting : ype 'Person' is missing the following properties from type 'Person[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more - I am sorry I don't reallyy get this type stuff too well - can you please advise ?

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this please ? I am sorry I keep asking it is just that I am not sure and nobody seems to know.

Comment: I have modified my answer, have u tried   it? Or send u code  and error msg again.